# UWP Windows 10 App memory increasing on navigation

Tags: c#, memory, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I have a UWP Windows 10 App and noticed the memory usage in task manager is increasing over time.

I stripped the App back and found the memory is increasing when the navigating pages. So I made a simple app with just a few pages to test and the memory is still increasing in this simple App. I have a MainPage that navigates a frame from Page1 to Page2 and back on a timer.

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    private DispatcherTimer _timer;

    private bool _page1Showing;
    private bool _timerRunning;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200);
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
    }

    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        GC.Collect();

        this.rootFrame.BackStack.Clear();
        this.rootFrame.ForwardStack.Clear();

        if (_page1Showing)
        {
            this.rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
            _page1Showing = false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
            _page1Showing = true;
        }
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_timerRunning)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            _timerRunning = false;
        }
        else
        {
            _timer.Start();
            _timerRunning = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Page1 and Page2 are empty pages with a grid with a background color so you can see the navigation. While this App runs the memory usage in task manager increases by around 1MB every 30 mins.

I have run the App using the memory diagnostics in VS2015 the Managed heap is as expected:

[image]

The heap is always increasing:

[image]

Comparing snapshots of the Heap shows:

[image]

I am confused what these McgInterop objects are? and why such a simple App is always increasing in memory usage. My main App needs to run for a long time (months+). Appreciate any help.

I have tried changing the pages NavigationCacheMode, if set to Required the pages are created once. If set to disabled the Pages are created every time, and I checked the finalizer is called as expected.

--

**Edit**: I added a button to start and stop the timer (updated the above). It seems that while the timer is running the memory usage in Task manager will increase, when the timer is stopped the memory usage eventually drops.

I measured the memory usage in task manager over a day starting and stopping the timer around every 2 hours as follows, it slowly increases and then drops at some point:

12.5 -> 17.1 -> 16.7 -> 13.9 -> 16.8 -> 22.5 -> 13.6 -> 14.6 -> 24.9 -> 15.2

So I guess everything is working fine? But I am not clear what is happening here, why is it increasing so much? When is it being free'd under what conditions?

Is the system delaying releasing memory while pages are navigating? when the user would normally be interacting with the screen?

Comment: The **Frame** keeps a navigation history. Does this still happen when you clear the backstack once in a while?

Comment: I updated the code above to clear the backstack, the memory still increases in task manager as before.

Comment: I wrote a demo(same with yours), and here is the memory usage graph: [the memory is NOT increasing except at the beginning](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2biFK.png) <br>
VS2015 with update1. <br>
Windows 10, 10586.
<br>
<br>
Added:
<br>
I think you do not have to call `GC.Collect();`every 200ms, the System will call for you. My demo has been running for almost 2 hours, and the memory is not keeping increasing, but it is changing a little.
<br>
Here is the documentation link about Memory Tool in Visual Studio: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/10/16/net-memory-analysis-enhancement

Comment: When you get a solution please share it in a self-answer. People in answers below (deleted) are asking for it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Every time you navigate to a Page, you create a new instance of Page, but the previous Page is not disposed (even if the Page is already in the navigation stack).

To prevent multiple allocation of same page, set `NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"` attribute to the Page.

Also, to minimize the memory allocation, you must override method `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom`.

In `OnNavigatedTo` method:

- Instantiate all memory intensive object or resources
- Add all events handlers you need
- starts all timers, tasks or threads

In `OnNavigatedFrom`:

- Dispose all resources
- Stops all timers, tasks or threads
- Remove references from all heavy objects
- Remove all events handlers
- Only if you really need, call GC.Collect()

Comment: From my question: I have tried changing the pages NavigationCacheMode, if set to Required the pages are created once. If set to disabled the Pages are created every time

Comment: @tagy22 If you use required, you risk to go out of memory, with enabled the OS cache the pages only if possible.
With disabled, the OS should automatically deallocate the instances to free the memory, before go out of memory, but from my experience it doesn't works very well.
Also if you use the cache, you must dispose the resources on 'OnNavigatedFrom', for example you can dispose the Timer instead just  stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Can we see your xaml code?  Are you using x:name in your xaml and is that being destroyed?  If so that might cause your memory leak.

Look at this link if you are using x:name:
http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/News/NewsItem/View/21/wpf-xname-memory-leak--how-to-clear-memory-in-scichart

Of course a UWP may handle x:name differently...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same problem on w8.1 with printingInline using charmBar it's consuming a lot of memory until crash of the application (1.5 GB). but normaly you don't need GC.colect() it's work automaticly .